# jquery reset append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reset after append() or before()? Please help. Many thanks in advance.

```
if((#tag_id).text() == 'something'){
   $(#tag_id).before("x");
}
// I want to reset the #tag_id to empty
$(#tag_id).val(''); // this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code example uses `.before()`. In this case, it would be better if `.before()` was given an element around `x` instead of just the text.

Then you could do this:

```
    // Wrap the "x" that you're inserting with <span> tags
$('#tag_id').before('<span>x</span>');

    // Use .prev() to reference the new <span> and remove it
$('#tag_id').prev().remove('span');​​​​​​​​​
```

Remember that using `.before()` does not place anything *inside* the `#tag_id`, but instead places it *before* the `#tag_id`.

If you meant for the content to go *inside* `#tag_id` but at the beginning, you would use `.prepend()`.

---

If your code is using `.append()`, one option would be to keep a reference to the element you're appending, and use that to remove it later.

```
var $appendElem = $('<div>some appended element</div>');

$appendElem.appendTo('#tag_id');
```

Then you can remove it via the same reference.

```
$appendElem.remove();
// or
$appendElem.detach();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the html inside of it, use:

```
$('#tag_id').html('');
```

If you want to remove the `id` attribute, use the `removeAttr`:

```
$('#tag_id').removeAttr('id');
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/
- http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 3):

If there are no handlers you can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) like this:

```
$('#tag_id').html('');
```

However if there are any event handlers or data on any objects in there you should use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) instead, like this:

```
$('#tag_id').empty();
```

`.html('')` won't clean up data/event handlers in `$.cache` where [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) and [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) will, if you're unsure, use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to avoid potential memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$("#tag_id").html("");
```